# CSS how to use calc with css variable (css properties) on left, translate etc properties

Tags: css, tabs

Please check my code, i want to use --index for each item, and when tab is active, it should have correct offset, then i can animate it. But only font-size property can take the parameter, left and translate they all not work. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my codepen.
https://codepen.io/geforcesong/pen/QWxPwZa

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
const tabClicked = (e)=>{
  if(e.target.classList.contains('active')){
    return;
  }
  items.forEach(item=>{
    item.classList.remove('active')
  })
  e.target.classList.add('active')
}

items.forEach(item=>{
  item.addEventListener('click', tabClicked)
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.item-container {
  width: 800px;
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.container .item {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: calc(5px * var(--index, 1));
}

.container .item.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.indicator {
  width: 150px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
/*   translate: calc(150px * var(--index)); */
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: calc(150px * var(--index));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div  class="item" style="--index:1">A sample</div>
    <div class="item active" style="--index:2">B sample</div>
    <div class="item" style="--index:3">C sample</div>
    <div class="item" style="--index:4">D sample</div>
  </div>
    
  <div class="indicator"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: --index is not defined for the div which has class indicator.

Answer (score 0):

set the --index property to the wrong elements, it won't tack effect when sibling's value change